# How to move away from verifyReceipt which has been deprecated?

Tags: app-store

Apple has deprecated verifyReceipt (), can someone help us to figure out how it should implemented going forward?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt

Comment: Hi Harald, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76438494/validating-receipts-with-the-app-store-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I guess they want us to move towards their App Store Server library (Node.js, Python, Swift or Java currently).
E.g. Java: https://github.com/apple/app-store-server-library-java?tab=readme-ov-file

Answer (score -2):

Set up a server-side endpoint or service that will handle the receipt verification process.

Make a POST request to the /verifyReceipt endpoint of the App Store Server API with the receipt data. You will need to include the receipt data in the request body as a JSON object.

Handle the response from the App Store Server API. The response will include information about the receipt, such as its validity, expiration date, and more.

Verify the response to ensure the authenticity of the receipt. You should check the status code and other relevant fields in the response to determine if the receipt is valid

Comment: "Make a POST request to the /verifyReceipt". This is the deprecated endpoint we use now and are trying to move away from!